# onActivityResult returns value too late

Tags: java, android, variables, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have 2D String array and I'm randomly picking one field. If it's empty, app pops out a window with editText and button, which will overwrite that field. Popup returns Intent with editText content and calls `finish()`.
I am trying to return a String out of function which `startActivityForResult(this,popupWindow)`. But it returns null instead, it overrides string later, when I don't want it to.

in activity one:

```
String returned_string_to_add;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [....]
    int[] thrown= throwCoin(cols,rows); //create int[2] with random numbers

    [....]
    if (board[thrown[0]][thrown[1]]==null){
        board[thrown[0]][thrown[1]]=addTask();
        Log.wtf( "check_board",  board[thrown[0]][thrown[1]]);
        Log.wtf( "intent",  returned_string_to_add);
    }
```

board is type `String[][]` initialized earlier.

out of `onCreate`, in activity one:

```
private String addTask() {
    returned_string_to_add=null;
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,PopupQuestion.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);

    //I expect to get results here.
    return returned_string_to_add;
}
    
    
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == 1)&&(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    
        returned_string_to_add=data.getStringExtra("String");
    
    }
    else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        returned_string_to_add=null;
   }
}
```

PopupQuestion:

```
[...]
onCreate
[...]
Intent intent =new Intent();
intent.putExtra("String",edittext.getText().toString()); //works fine
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

I want returned_string_to_add to be overwriten in function `addTask()`, but it happens later. How to fix this?

Comment: "I expect to get results here." - that wont happen. You need to use the `onActivityResult` callback to get your result.

Comment: any idea how to make it work properly?

Comment: `data.getStringExtra("String")` - Have you verified that this is called and contains the correct value?

Comment: yes, it works fine, The only problem is with synchronization, I need this data in specific time. And it overwrites returned_string_to_add bit too late.

https://imgur.com/a/gChXSf1

Comment: You really don't need that data until `PopupQuestion` returns to the first `Activity`. While `PopupQuestion` is open, the user won't be doing anything with the first `Activity`, anyway.

Comment: You are partly right, I don't need anything from popup unless i'ts finished. But as it finishes, app doesn't call onActivityResult() immediately. And that's the problem. I need overwritten returned_string_to_add exactly where I'm calling startActivityForResult(intent,1); and it seems not overwritting during this onCreate(); at all.

Comment: "But as it finishes, app doesn't call onActivityResult() immediately." – Sure it does. "I need overwritten returned_string_to_add exactly where I'm calling startActivityForResult(intent,1);" – You can't get it there. You need to restructure your code so that whatever needs to be done with the result is executed from `onActivityResult()`. You cannot return the expected value from `addTask()`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Are there any easy-fixes? ways around?

Comment: It depends on what is currently trying to use the `addTask()` return. Basically, you need to change that `String whatever = addTask();`, `next code...` to be just `addTask();`, and `next code...` would be executed from `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. As You said, re-arranging code and adding few global variables made it work!